# Error al imprimir el tiempo en python

Tags: python, date

Hola estuve haciendo un código sencillo en Python de una suma de potencias, al querer saber el tiempo de ejecución de la función con diferentes valores en el terminal me imprime un 0.0 como si no hubiera pasado nada de tiempo, pero cuando intento hacer una grafica del tiempo si me salen valores, en el terminal trate de imprimir el tiempo para el resultado1 y resultado2 pero me sigue saliendo 0.0
alguien podría decirme que esta pasando? porque no me imprime el tiempo?

```
import sys 
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



def suma_potencias (numero_de_sumas):
    i = 1
    potencia=1
    suma=0
    while i <= numero_de_sumas:
        potencia= pow(i,i)
        suma= potencia +suma
        i=i+1
    return suma


if __name__=='__main__':
    
    tiempo_numeros=[]

    tic1= time.time()
    numero_5= suma_potencias (5)
    toc1= time.time()
    resultado1=toc1-tic1
    print(resultado1)

    tic2=time.time()
    numero_10= suma_potencias (10)
    toc2=time.time()
    resultado2=toc2-tic2
    print(resultado2)

    tic3=time.time()
    numero_100= suma_potencias (100)
    toc3=time.time()
    resultado3=toc3-tic3

    tic4=time.time()
    numero_500= suma_potencias (500)
    toc4=time.time()
    resultado4=toc4-tic4
    
    tic5=time.time()
    numero_1000= suma_potencias (1000)
    toc5=time.time()
    resultado5=toc5-tic5
    
    x=[5, 10,100,500,1000]
    y=[resultado1, resultado2, resultado3, resultado4, resultado5]


    plt.plot(x,y,label='Numeros')
    plt.legend()
    plt.xlabel("Iteraciones")
    plt.ylabel("resultados")
    plt.savefig("grafica4.png")
    plt.close()
    numero_de_sumas=3
    print(suma_potencias(numero_de_sumas))
```

esto me imprime en el terminal:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: y si imprimes `y` que obtienes?

Comment: @Christian lo imprimí y sigo obteniendo 0.0, es posible que una función tarde 0.0 ? :(

Comment: sí, es posile...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`time.time()` retorna el tiempo en segundos. Si ejecute el código original obtengo:

```
4.0531158447265625e-06
4.76837158203125e-06
32

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Lo que me dice que los tiempos son de ~4x10^-6 segundos, o ~4ms. Por alguna razón tu ambiente simplemente lo reduce a 0.0 (¿nos muestras el mismo código que ejecutas?).

`time.time_ns()` retorna el tiempo en nanosegundos, si reemplazas una por la otra y ejecutas el mismo código, obtendras estos valores:

```
3942
4352
32

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Lo que dice que el código toma alrededor de 4 ms en ejecutarse.

Ambos valores concuerdan, lo que nos dice que tu resultado es correcto y que simplemente debes cambiar a una unidad de medida más apropiada: milisegundos en lugar de segundos.

Comment: Hola, curiosamente lo estoy haciendo en un entorno virtual de visual estudio code en windows, lo he pasado a mi maquina virtual de ubuntu y si me arroja casi los mismos valores que en tu caso... nose que es lo que pasa quizás el entorno visual que nos dijo mi profe con el venv no esta funcionando de manera correcta, creo que trabajare solo en ubuntu, gracias

Answer (score 2):

Otra alternativa más sencilla es usar el módulo integrado `timeit` [(Documentación)](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/timeit.html) que se usa para este tipo de cosas precisamente.

```
import sys
import time
import timeit

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def suma_potencias(numero_de_sumas):
    i = 1
    potencia = 1
    suma = 0
    while i <= numero_de_sumas:
        potencia = pow(i, i)
        suma = potencia + suma
        i = i + 1
    return suma


if __name__ == "__main__":

    sumas = [5, 10, 100, 500, 1000]
    resultados = []
    muestras = 10

    for suma in sumas:
        resultados.append(timeit.timeit(lambda: suma_potencias(suma), number=muestras))

    for resultado, suma in zip(resultados, sumas):
        print(f"La suma {suma} ha tardado {resultado} segundos")

    x = sumas
    y = resultados

    plt.plot(x, y, label="Números")
    plt.legend()
    plt.xlabel("Iteraciones")
    plt.ylabel("resultados")
    plt.savefig("grafica4.png")
    plt.close()
```

Ese codigo devuelve en mi máquina...

```
La suma 5 ha tardado 1.9700000000066886e-05 segundos
La suma 10 ha tardado 3.56000000000245e-05 segundos
La suma 100 ha tardado 0.0005893999999999622 segundos
La suma 500 ha tardado 0.012278699999999976 segundos
La suma 1000 ha tardado 0.07943049999999996 segundos
```

[image: Resultado MATPLOT]

El uso es un poco trampa pero no es difícil

```
timeit.timeit(nombredelafuncionsinargumentos, number=numeroderepeticiones)
```

Eso devuelve el tiempo que tarda en segundos en ejecutar la función `nombredelafuncionsinargumentos` "number" veces (para tener una muestra y calcular un valor medio de tiempo porque no siempre tarda exactamente lo mismo puesto que tu pc puede estar ocupado haciendo otras cosas).

La trampa está en que solo acepta el nombre de la función sin argumentos; si quieres usar argumentos tienes que usar un `lambda`

```
timeit.timeit(lambda: nombredelafuncion(argumentos), number=numeroderepeticiones)
```

Answer (score 0):

La resolucion de time.time() es bastante menor que time.perf_counter(), puedes comprobarlo tu mismo viendo la resolución de ambas funciones:

```
print(time.get_clock_info('time'))
print(time.get_clock_info('perf_counter'))
```

En este caso te recomiendo usar time.perf_counter() en lugar de time.time().

Por cierto, time.time_ns() lo único que hará será devolverte lo mismo que time.time() pero en nanosegundos, es decir, seguirás recibiendo 0.0